# ngrx createFeatureSelector with two type arguments

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am learning ngrx and currently using v6.0.1 with Angular v6.0.9 and AngularCLI v6.0.8.

The example app shows how to create a root level createFeatureSelector with two type arguments like this:

```
example-app/app/reducers/index.ts

.....

export const getLayoutState = createFeatureSelector<State, fromLayout.State>(
  'layout'
);
```

When I try to reproduce this sample in my app, the compiler complains that createFeatureSelector needs 1 argument but I supplied 2.

I have been investigating and found when I navigate in vscode by pressing F12 on the imported createFeatureSelector function in my app, it takes me to the line shown here:

```
selector.d.ts
.....

export declare function createSelectorFactory<T = any, V = any>(memoize: MemoizeFn): (...input: any[]) => Selector<T, V>;
export declare function createSelectorFactory<T = any, V = any>(memoize: MemoizeFn, options: SelectorFactoryConfig<T, V>): (...input: any[]) => Selector<T, V>;
export declare function createFeatureSelector<T>(featureName: string): MemoizedSelector<object, T>;
/\/\/\
```

There are no more exported fuctions in the selector.d.ts file.

However, when I downloaded the ngrx platform repo and navigated on the same line, I end up on this line:

```
selector.ts
.....

export function createFeatureSelector<T>(
  featureName: string
): MemoizedSelector<object, T>;
export function createFeatureSelector<T, V>(
  featureName: keyof T
): MemoizedSelector<T, V>;
/\/\/\/\/\
export function createFeatureSelector(
  featureName: any
): MemoizedSelector<any, any> {
  return createSelector(
    (state: any) => state[featureName],
    (featureState: any) => featureState
  );
}
```

This looks more accurate because the signature contains two type arguments.

Am I doing something wrong to where I'm getting the wrong version of @ngrx/store when I add it to my package.json? This is a sample:

```
....
"moment": "2.22.2",
"npm": "^6.1.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "6.0.1",
"@ngrx/router-store": "6.0.1",
"@ngrx/store": "6.0.1",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "6.0.1",
"ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
"primeng": "^5.2.7",
"rxjs": "6.2.1",
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a unreleased feature which will become available in the next release.
You can use the code below for now.

```
export const getLayoutState = createFeatureSelector<fromLayout.State>('layout');
```

Answer (score 1):

you only need to pass the interface for the state you want to create selector for like following:

```js
export interface LayoutState {
  layout: fromLayout.State;
  somethingElse: fromsomethingElse.State;
  ...: .....;
}

export const getLayoutState = createFeatureSelector<LayoutState>('layout')
```

Layout state is just an interface for better typing and help IDE's.

Comment: that makes sense but I want to use both! I'm new to npm packages and wonder if it is a bug where the ngrx folks forgot to regenerate the selector.d.ts file and should I issue a bug on github.

Comment: you need to import it from ```@ngrx/store```. make sure you are importing it from right place.

Answer (score 0):

- EDIT - Resolved by the accepted answer from Tim the ngrx developer.

I have created a bug on the ngrx repo for my issue and will update here with progress.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1191